# Jquery Datatables requested unknown parameter problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I've been having this issue for a few weeks now and every time I try to find the solution I am unsuccessful so I am hoping one of you can spot my mistake. I've used the datatable debugger, which gave no errors.
I am using datatables in a Django project with the following structure. Javascript in a file with the following code:

```
function redraw_exceptions(week_limit) {

  var table = $('#testTable').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "api/exceptions/data",
      "datatype": 'json',
      "data": {
        "week_limit": week_limit,
        "type": 1,
      },
      "columns": [
              { "data": "col1" },
              { "data": "col2" },
              { "data": "col3", className: "test123" },
          ]
    },
  });
}
```

Then a html page where the Table is defined and where on document ready I run the javascript function.

```
<table class="table" id="testTable">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Col1</th>
  <th>Col2</th>
  <th>Col3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
  redraw_exceptions(4)
})
{%
```

Now the problem comes. Whenever the json data is structured as follows

```
{"data": [["1", "9908", "171.74"], ["2", "9959", "156.83"], ["3", "457", "153.83"], ["4", "452", "147.73"], ["5", "9927", "141.90"], ["6", "9953", "139.44"], ["7", "9915", "137.75"], ["8", "9935", "135.29"], ["9", "9952", "130.97"], ["10", "9925", "128.79"], ["11", "9934", "128.34"], ["12", "309", "127.73"], ["13", "9957", "126.08"], ["14", "451", "125.56"], ["15", "9945", "125.00"], ["16", "9921", "120.31"], ["17", "9951", "118.22"], ["18", "9926", "118.09"], ["19", "9943", "117.98"], ["20", "9954", "115.22"], ["21", "9901", "115.22"], ["22", "9939", "112.33"]]}
```

It works (so the table actually gets the correct data), but I cannot add classes to the table entries because I think it cannot find the right columns since the data is not proper JSON. 
But when the data is proper JSON the table simply does not get filled and I get the error '**Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0**'. The data looks like this then:

```
{"data": [{"col1": "1", "col2": "9908", "col3": "171.74"}, {"col1": "2", "col2": "9959", "col3": "156.83"}, {"col1": "3", "col2": "457", "col3": "153.83"}, {"col1": "4", "col2": "452", "col3": "147.73"}, {"col1": "5", "col2": "9927", "col3": "141.90"}, {"col1": "6", "col2": "9953", "col3": "139.44"}, {"col1": "7", "col2": "9915", "col3": "137.75"}, {"col1": "8", "col2": "9935", "col3": "135.29"}, {"col1": "9", "col2": "9952", "col3": "130.97"}, {"col1": "10", "col2": "9925", "col3": "128.79"}]}
```

I thought it might be because the Ajax request also has data, so when I changed the columns data to for instance 'test' and also did this in the JSON data I do not get the same error anymore, but I get the following error in my console: '**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.length**')'.

If anyone has any clue what I can do to fix this problem, I really really appreciate it!

Comment: Have you try: "columnDefs": [
    { className: "test123", "targets": [ 0 ] }
  ] Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code **http://jsfiddle.net/k8pyjz5d/** you simply just not close the `ajax` section correct, by that `columns` accidently becomes part of `ajax`.

Comment: This is indeed the correct asnwer. Furthermore, I needed to cast all variables to strings before they would be properly showed in my datatable. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `columns.createdCell`

there are 5 parameters

```
function createdCell( cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex )
```

you can use get more detailed information to https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell

In the below example, last column color is changed by `red` while creating cell event :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    redraw_exceptions(4)
})

function redraw_exceptions(week_limit) {

    var testdata = [{
        "col1": "1",
        "col2": "9908",
        "col3": "171.74",
    }, {
        "col1": "2",
        "col2": "9959",
        "col3": "156.83",
    }, {
        "col1": "3",
        "col2": "457",
        "col3": "153.83",
    }, {
        "col1": "4",
        "col2": "452",
        "col3": "147.73",
    }, {
        "col1": "5",
        "col2": "9927",
        "col3": "141.90",
    }];

    $('#testTable').DataTable({
        "aaData": testdata,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "col1" },
            { "mDataProp": "col2" },
            { "mDataProp": "col3" }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": '_all',
            "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                if (colIndex == 2) {
                    $(td).css('color', 'red')
                }
            }
        }]
    });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table class="table" id="testTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: @davidkonrad, He want to add class to column, He said that "I cannot add classes to the table entries because I think it cannot find the right columns since the data is not proper JSON."

Comment: Hey @saAction, Now I see, OK, but a class *will* be added to each cell of the column if we use `className` (try inspect col3 in my fiddle above). `createdCell` is more if you want to manipulate the DOM node further or perhaps want to add different classes to different cells. But if you just need to add a class to all `<td></td>` in a column `className` suit the needs. Just saying :)